# Sharing Lisp symbols across packages

Tags: common-lisp, package, symbols

I have a function `foo` defined in a package `my-package`:

```
(in-package :my-package)
(defun foo (a)
  (if (eql a 'value1)
    (do-this)
    (do-the-other)))
```

When I call this function from a different package I have to qualify the parameter with the package name:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(my-package:foo 'my-package::value1)
```

but this is rather ugly. I want to share the symbol `value1` with all other packages.
I found one workaround which is to import the symbol `value1`, but this only works if it has been already defined in the other package.
Another possibility is to pass strings, `"value1"`, but again, this is just a patch.
What is the best way to share symbols across packages?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually keywords are used for this purpose. If you want to use non-keyword symbols, just export (and import if you don't want to use the package qualified name) the symbol the same way you do with all other symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Use a keyword symbol, which you can always write without naming its package `keyword`:

```
(foo:bar :value1)
```

Keyword symbols are in the `KEYWORD` package, are evaluating to themselves, are automatically exported and you don't need to write down the package name.

Since a keyword symbol evaluates to itself, you even don't have to quote them - but you can.

```
(foo:bar ':value1)
```

**Alternative: short package names**

Sometimes it might be useful to have a symbol in a specific package. Then I would use a short package name, which you can also define as a nickname. See the options on `DEFPACKAGE`. For example the package `color-graphics` could have the nickname `cg`.

Then one would write:

```
(foo:bar 'cg:green)
```

Since it is a normal symbol, you have to quote it, otherwise it would be a variable.